# Unable to dispaly line graph using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
};
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
      return x(d.IP);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return y(d.count);
    });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
    "IP": "192.168.12.1",
    "count": "100"
}, {
    "IP": "76.09.45.34",
    "count": "200"
}, {
    "IP": "34.91.23.76",
    "count": "300"
}, {
    "IP": "192.168.19.32",
    "count": "400"
}, {
    "IP": "192.168.10.89",
    "count": "500"
}, {
    "IP": "192.168.12.98",
    "count": "600"
}];

data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.IP = d.IP;
    d.count = +d.count;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.IP;
    }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.count;
    })]);

svg.append("path")
.attr("d", valueline(data));

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .data(data)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .data(data);
```

```css
body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}
path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me . I am stuck. I don't know how to get the `x axis` and the *line graph* using these codes. I am new to `D3`, so I am confused. Every time I make any more change the axis goes off. These are the last codes that I tried till now but I am only getting the `y axis` and its labels but no `x axis` and the line is also not getting drawn.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Linear scale` which expects only integer range so you need to use `ordinal scale` for x-axis.

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.IP;
    }))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1); 
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.count;
    })]);
```

Here's your [working code.](http://jsbin.com/mijuhew/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ordinal scales for x axis.

> Ordinal scales have a discrete domain, such as a set of names or
>   categories.

Reference: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales

Here is the working code snippet:

```js
var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
};

var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.IP);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.count);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
  "IP": "192.168.12.1",
  "count": "100"
}, {
  "IP": "76.09.45.34",
  "count": "200"
}, {
  "IP": "34.91.23.76",
  "count": "300"
}, {
  "IP": "192.168.19.32",
  "count": "400"
}, {
  "IP": "192.168.10.89",
  "count": "500"
}, {
  "IP": "192.168.12.98",
  "count": "600"
}];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.IP = d.IP;
  d.count = +d.count;
});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.IP
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.count;
})]);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", valueline(data));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px Arial;
}
path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Gillsha for your help. I was really stuck. Your code works like a charm. I need to get in depth knowledge of D3. Thank you. : ~ )